# Can I prevent the CSS property Content from overriding the min-height property?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, dragula

I am using Dragula to implement Drag and Drop on some of my MVC views.

There will be times when either the source or target areas will be empty.

In the case where either is empty, I would like to show a 'placeholder' with a min-height and dashed border with the text "Drop Here..." to make it visually clearer for the user what to do.

I added a class called CheckEmpty on the parent, and in CSS added:

```
.CheckEmpty:empty::after {
min-height:4em;
background-color:lightcyan;
border:dashed 2px #D9D9D9;
border-radius: 5px;  
content: "Drop Here...";
}
```

The problem though is that the content property seems to override the min-height and the border surrounds the text only. Removing the content property allows the CSS to display the placeholder correctly with the correct min-height and it also fills the width of the container.

[image: Incorrect]

[image: Without Text]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening or do I need to tackle this from a different angle?

Comment: Try line-height instead of min-height. It gives you middle alignment too...

Comment: Why do you have to use content property. If your element is a html div element then you could add text "Drop here..." add padding, min-width,and line-height as per your requirement. I think pseudo classes are not necessary here.

Comment: The parent div which has the class CheckEmpty is populated with its child div's from an Ajax call, and I really only wanted to show the placeholder if there are no child div's, without using javascript to remove the placeholder if not empty. Looks like I might have to go that route though.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for us to check.?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ou46nedb/   This is the basic code, not sure if I should add anything else, although the CSS is not displaying the placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the `content` but it's about `::after` ! `::after` destroys all styles about size in Dragula. So, It's better instead of `after` use simple CSS and add your content by code or directly in HTML tags:

```
.CheckEmpty {
    min-height:4em;    
    background-color:lightcyan;
    border:dashed 2px #D9D9D9;
    border-radius: 5px;     

}

(".CheckEmpty").html("Drop Here2...");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ou46nedb/4/

Answer (score 0):

I never did get this working with CSS only so in the end went back to using javascript to check if the div was empty and applying the required css class.